# Weird problem using custom fields

Tags: css

I am trying to pull content from specific categories and have them appear on the homepage along with an image that is pulled from the custom field for that entry.  Everything looks like it is working ok.. and the second entry works as it should, however with the first entry, only the image links back to the post, the title and read more link are not recognized by the mouse as links.  Looking at the html, it seems like the php is printing everything as it should, so I figured it must be a CSS problem, but I cleared all the relevant styles and the links still are not recognized.

Here is the php I have for the home page

```
<?php
// Show custom fields from Food Category
query_posts('showposts=2&cat=3'); ?> 
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
// This is added to show <!--more--> on home page
global $more;
$more = 0;
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
<img src="<?php
$values = get_post_custom_values("food_thumb"); echo $values[0]; ?>" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="span-3">
<p class="smallTitle">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></p></div>
<div class="span-1 theDate">
 <?php the_time('m.d.y') ?>
</div> 
<div class="span-4">
<?php the_content('<span class="moretext">Read more...</span>'); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The HTML output looks fine..

```
<div class="span-4 fixed-height-sidebar">        
<div class="smallthumb"><a href="http://southendseattle.com/?p=24" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Food Test 1"><img src="foodthumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>

<div class="span-3">
<p class="smallTitle"><a href="http://.com/?p=24" rel="bookmark">
Food Test 1</a></p></div>
<div class="span-1 theDate">
 07.16.09</div> 
<div class="span-4 fixed-height-sidebar">
<p>Mmmmmmmm.  Food.  Aliquam libero libero, luctus ut tristique pulvinar, euismod at diam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,   <a href="http://southendseattle.com/?p=24#more-24" class="more-link"><span class="moretext">Read more&#8230;</span></a></p>
</div>
<div class="smallthumb"><a href="http://.com/?p=3" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Food test page -2"><img src="http://.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/foodthumb2.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="span-3">
<p class="smallTitle"><a href="http://.com/?p=3" rel="bookmark">
Food test page -2</a></p></div>
<div class="span-1 theDate">
 07.12.09</div> 
<div class="span-4">
<p>“Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In nec odio vitae nunc euismod vulputate. Integer aliquam ullamcorper tortor, nec suscipit magna viverra in. Nunc urna neque, dapibus id congue et, dignissim vitae augue. Aliquam et bibendum lacus.  <a href="http://southendseattle.com/?p=3#more-3" class="more-link"><span class="moretext">Read more&#8230;</span></a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot to help explain my problem...

[alt text http://zacharydesigns.com/temp/wpsample.jpg](http://zacharydesigns.com/temp/wpsample.jpg)

Comment: Are those URLs in your HTML output the actual URLs, or did you truncate them?  Those http://.com/?p=3 URLs are probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I took your HTML output, and pasted it into a blank HTML page (adding the HTML/HEAD/BODY tags). Both links rendered and worked correctly. I tested in Firefox and IE. From the looks of it, your HTML output is just fine.

Any chance you could post the output of the entire page?

--Adam

Comment: Yea, thanks, thats what I said above.. HTML output is fine.  The entire page is super long so I just posted the part that is effected.  I think this more has to do with me messing up the Wordpress loop somehow.

Answer (score 0):

What does `fixed-height-sidebar` do in the CSS?

That's the only difference between the two entries.

Comment: oh that is a remnant of a former draft.. it does nothing